# Complex LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have the following LINQ to SQL query where I want to pass a specific string based on the bool value in the database.

```
                stuffList = data.Users.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => result.Contains(x.usrName))
                    .Select(d => new mTeachers(d.usrName, d.usrAge, "male/female"))
                    .ToList();
```

Instead of `"male/female"` string I want to pass either `male` or `female` string depending on the d.usrSex bool value in the Users database (if usrSex == true then I pass "male" string). How can I put `if` condition in there to check the bool value?

Comment: Rather than passing a string labelled "male" or "female" it would have to make more sense to pass a `bool` value like `isMale` to the `mTeachers` object. Strings aren't a very useful way of holding this type of information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ternary operator

```
new mTeachers(d.usrName, (int)d.usrAge, d.usrSex ? "male" : "female")
```